# Check if user is an admin by username or email only

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating an admin section from scratch. The users for this should be users from a wordpress site where they have administrator privileges. So I am currently authenticating the users using

```
if( (!user_pass_ok($user, $pass)){
    //login fail
}else{
    //successful login
}
```

But I also want to know if the user is an administrator. What I came across by looking online is they use the `current_user_can( 'administrator' )`. But in my case, the user has not yet logged in. All I have to check if the user is an admin, is the username/email address the user enters for login. How can I check if this user is an admin by only the username/email?

Comment: Just a side note: user_pass_ok() is deprecated, use wp_authenticate instead (note that it returns a WP_User or a WP_Error): https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in a comment `user_pass_ok( $user, $pass )` is deprecated in favor of [wp_authenticate](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate).

Additionally, WordPress has an amazing [Capabilities API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) that goes far beyond Roles.  I would strongly recommend reading up on it.

For a brief example, if I wanted to grant a user access to manage WordPress options (a capability called `manage_options` that is inherited from the Administrator role), all I have to do is say `current_user_can('manage_options')` or use the `WP_User->has_cap(...)` function.

Matching based on capabilities is usually much more flexible that matching on a Role... for example imagine my site had a second role called "Developers". If you gated access based on roles, and you wanted to give users in the developer role access to your feature, you would need to add a second check whenever you need to verify a users permissions: `($role == 'administrator' || $role == 'developer')`

So, if you have a user logged in already then you can always verify their capabilities with:

```
current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) // all admins have 'manage_options'
```

or define your own custom cap, give it to all administrators:

```
function add_custom_admin_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'administrator' );

    $role->add_cap( 'access_my_admin_zone' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_custom_admin_caps');
```

and check the custom cap against the current user

```
current_user_can( 'access_my_admin_zone' )
```

The added benefit to capabilities is that WordPress will automatically check the current user's permissions when rendering the WP Admin menu if you register your admin section with one of the add_*_page functions ([add_menu_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)) and a capability like 'manage_options'

```
add_menu_page ( $title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position)
```

Lastly, It was a bit unclear as to whether you were logging in users yourself, if so I would propose this alternative if you are logging in the user from scratch (i.e. not using WordPress's login form):

```
$user = wp_authenticate( $user, $pass );

if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && $user->has_cap( 'manage_options' ) ) {
   // success
} else {
   // fail
}
```

You will also need to call `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )` during every page load of your custom admin to verify that the user is logged in and has permissions, if that fails, then direct them to your custom login page... or possibly, the wordpress login page with [auth_redirect()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect).

Comment: this code doesn't work. it authenticates and logs in before checking if user is an admin or not

Comment: A bit lost on what you are trying to accomplish here now... updated answer to go more in depth on using caps...  A) are you just building an additional admin page/section with add_menu_page? If so, I hope my recent edits are helpful. or B) are you writing a completely new WP Admin and just leveraging the core functionality? (your usage of `user_pass_ok` seemed to hint toward this approach)

Comment: I am creating a completely new, non-wordpress admin site using PHP. This site acts as a data admin section for a website that's created using wordpress. So users for that site are saved in the wp_users table. All I want to do is to allow the users with administrator privileges on that table to login to my site. That's it

Comment: Alright, then my original answer is close. Only thing is you will need to add a call to `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )` on every page load (no way around this) to make sure that the user is A) is logged in B) still logged in C) still an admin

Comment: I tried combining the two arguments, can you please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854379/using-wordpress-authentication-while-checking-is-user-is-an-administrator

Answer (score 2):

```
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );    
if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {  
    //User has administrator privilidges 
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `$user_id` here is the value I get from the user. Nope, this doesn't work

Comment: If you get username from the end user you have to find out the user_id.

Comment: but, where do I add the `wp_authenticate($user, $pass)` part?