# Using WordPress authentication while checking if user is an administrator

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am trying to use wordpress authentication for an admin site I am creating using PHP. I only want users with the role Administrator to be able to login to this site. This is what I have:

```
if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('User is an admin!')</script>";
    if( !wp_authenticate($user, $pass) ){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Wrong password!')</script>";
    }elseif(!wp_authenticate($user, $pass) ){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Correct password!')</script>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You're not an admin!')</script>";
}
```

And this is how I query the db to get the user ID:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username,$password ,$db );
$q1 = " SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE 
    user_email=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $q1);
if($stmt){

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        //echo $id;
        $user = get_userdata( $id );   

}
```

I get the alert "User is an admin" and then it shows a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: This question is related to [Check if user is an admin by username or email only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785381/check-if-user-is-an-admin-by-username-or-email-only/36785999?noredirect=1#comment61276507_36785999)

Second: the logic in your first block is very strange... this is what is should resemble

## Use WordPress Login Workflow

You should always use the built in WordPress login form and authentication workflow. It is not that hard to use and rolling your own login page makes your application **very insecure** unless you do it **exactly right**

To use the default WordPress login flow, put something like this in your Dashboard's common PHP file

```
<?php 
require_once 'path/to/wp-load.php';
// Before every page load
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Not logged in at all... redirect to WP Login Page
    auth_redirect();
    exit(); // Exit to be safe
} elseif ( ! in_array( 'administrator', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {
    wp_logout(); // Destroy their login session
    wp_die('You must be an administrator'); // Die with a nice error page
}
```

Let me explain this workflow:

First we import `wp-load.php`.  This is somewhat frowned upon as well and there might be a lighter way of doing this, but for now it should work well

Now, say a user loads https://example.com/my-admin/index.php, your `common.php` will first check if the user is logged in. If **not** then it will call `auth_redirect()` and exit which will redirect the user to https://example.com/wp-login.php?return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmy-admin%2Findex.php

The user will login using the wp-login page and then they will be redirected back to https://example.com/my-admin/index.php, where your `common.php` will now recognize `is_logged_in()` as true... so we step to the next elseif where it will check if the user is an administrator.  If not then it will kill their authentication session and fail with a wp_die We kill the auth session so that if they reload the page they will be brought back to the login page to enter credentials for an admin and not repeatedly shown the `wp_die` page, you can tweak this however you wish as this might not be the desired behavior (perhaps redirect to /wp-admin/... or provide a link in the wp_die for the regular /wp-admin/)

if they do have the Administrator role, then execution of the request will continue and the dashboard will be accessible.

Please note that for this to work you will need to have your dashboard running on the same domain as your WordPress install... or else the cookies won't transfer over.

## Roll your own login page. This is bad practice

It is hard to do... this example doesn't include Nonces, honeypots, or any other security features that you will get with the standard login form (either with default core or from additional plugins)

```
<?php 
// Your login.php page

// Really, no really, this should just be done with WordPress's default login page with an auth_redirect()
// Really this is not recommended, it's really bad practice, and much less secure
// You've been warned

// If they provided a username and password, then check them
if ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) && isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
  $username = $_POST['username']
  $username = $_POST['password']
  // Check the username and password with WordPress to see if they are for any user
  $user = wp_authenticate( $username, $password );
  $error = '';
  if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
      // Verify that the user is an admin
      if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
          // Redirect them to the dashboard
          wp_redirect('dashboard.php');
          exit();
      } else {
          $error = "Correct password, but not an Admin : (";
      }
  } else {
      $error = "Wrong password :(";
  }
}
// The Login Page
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title> My Login </title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <?php if ( $error ): ?>
       <div class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <label>
    Username:
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required />
    </label>
    <label>
    Password:
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required />
    </label>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Before you load any other page besides your login page you should have this code

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || ! in_array( 'administrator', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {
    wp_redirect('login.php?error=Please%20Login');
    exit();
}
// now you can do your stuff
```

Comment: okay, so how do I use  WordPress's default login page as a login page for my site?

Comment: I outlined how to use it in my answer, you need to have a common php file that is included for each page in your custom dashboard/admin.  This should be something that you should have anyways.  In that file you should have something like the code I outlined

Comment: okay, so I added the first block of your answer to my common php but it doesn't seem to work. And in that code, where does it say, "if credentials are correct, go to my-admin-site"?

Comment: got it working using the 2nd block of your code, but would still like to learn the answer for my question in the previous comment

Comment: Edited with some more explaination